# Passing PHP variables to jQuery pop-up DIV

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I'm quite new to PHP and I'm dealing with a problem I have no idea how to solve. I'm generating a table of users (name, username, e-mail) from a MySQL database. There is an edit link in each row. This links displays a pop-up DIV (made using jQuery) that contains three form fields (name, username, e-mail) that can be used to edit (update) the particular row.

I would like to pre-load the current values from the database into these form fields to make it more convenient to edit them.

The problem is that the DIV is displayed without refreshing the web page, meaning that I'm unable to pass any parameters from the edit link and therefore I cannot tell the server which values to pre-load.

Is there any solution to this?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to use AJAX to send the request and recieve a response without refreshing the page. Look at `$.ajax()` in jQuery. https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 1):

You can pass them using this way:

Note : when u generate the values(name,username,email) in Server (using PHP)..do it as follows :

```
<a class='editBtn' data-x="the username info" data-y="the email info" data-z="name">Edit</a>
```

then at Client side catch them using on click events:

```
jQuery('.editBtn').each(function(i,v){
      jQuery(v).click(function(eve){
         eve.preventDefault();
         eve.stopPropagation();
         var username= jQuery(v).attr('data-x');
         var email= jQuery(v).attr('data-y');
         var name= jQuery(v).attr('data-z');
          /*
         display ur Modal Box here
         Happy Coding :) ,

         */


      });

 });
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$(your var in JS) = <?PHP echo $(your rowname in the prepaired statement)['(your ID tablevariable)'];?>
```

that could work but i hadn't seen the code so, this is the only thing i could give tou to try

Answer (score 0):

if you want to refresh the data in realtime about your html with your new values, you must use AJAX. JQuery give us a simple api about this: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

I like to use a hidden `<iframe>` at the bottom of all my pages.  I can load a php script into that, which than can be used to update the parent frame by using javascript.

```
<iframe name="hidden" id="hidden" style="display:none"></iframe>
```

To call the script, just use a link or button to call it.

```
<a href="myscript.php?uniqID=1" target="hidden">Click to load script!</a>
```

Once you get the data from mysql, use javascript to change the variables.

```
<script language="javascript">
  parent.document.getElementById('name').value = '<?PHP= $sqlResults['name']; ?>';
  parent.document.getElementById('username').value = '<?PHP= $sqlResults['username']; ?>';
  parent.document.getElementById('email').value = '<?PHP= $sqlResults['email']; ?>';
</script>
```